# apache httpd access log to show accesses resulting from directory listing clicks

Tags: apache, http, logging

I am curious about two things: 
1. Does access_log in Apache 2.4 track requests resulting from file clicks in directory listing?
2. Is there a way to filter access logs to show these requests?

Let me broaden the question: under what circumstances does the access-log not show a path to the requested file?

Comment: Well, at least for point 1. you could easily check by yourself?

Comment: My reading of the access logs is that directory listings don't show the exact path of the files requested, but I was hoping to get a confirmation of this.